# Why isn't my html/javascript code working?

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

I'm trying to make it so when I go to the site, there's a button and when you press it, it prompts you for "What's the password?" To determine if it's correct, I'm using concat strings to take the prompt answer and add .html to the end, and I want it to redirect to (passwordtheyenter).html, so if they enter "test" as the password, it'll take them to "test.html"

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function testFunction() {
        var str1 = prompt.("What's the password?");
        var str2 = ".html";
        var pass = str1.concat(str2);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="testFunction()">Chat</button>


<script>
    open.window(pass)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `prompt.()`? You should open the console (F12 in most browsers). It will let you know if there are errors in your code.

Comment: What happens if someone tries a few passwords and finds a page that you didn't want them to see?

Comment: you should never EVER use client side validation as your primary means of authentication.

Comment: I don't really know how to reply on this site, I registered to ask this. @HoboSapiens I'm only going to have this page and the redirect one

Comment: I don't really know how to reply on this site, I registered to ask this.@MatthewRath This isn't for something really important, and I don't need to save the data to log in later, but if you still have any suggestions I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Guys, I think he is just learning Javascript, not building NSA's new website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four primary reasons your HTML/Javscript code is not working correctly.

First off, the scope of the variable `pass` is only defined within the function and so it can only be accessed within that function.  Define it outside of the function, then set its value within.

Edit: Because `pass` is now only being used by the function, it doesn't need to be defined outside of it.

Next, I believe you were trying to use the window.open() function.  You wrote open.window() in your code.

Third, you accidentally had a period after the prompt() call

Fourth, you should have the window.open() call within the function so that it doesn't run until the use actually clicks the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function testFunction() {
            var str1 = prompt("What's the password?");
            var str2 = ".html";
            var pass = str1 + str2;
            window.open(pass);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="testFunction()">Chat</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Drew If you have the `window.open` call inside `testFunction` then you don't need to make the `pass` variable global

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your code are as follows:

1. `prompt.()` is syntactically invalid Javascript code. It will give you an error, which can be seen in the console (you can open it by hitting F12 in most browsers, or CTRL+SHIFT+I in Opera).
2. `open.window()` is semantically invalid Javascript code. The is no global variable `open`. What you probably wanted here is `window.open(...)`.
3. The way your code is written does not make much sense. When the button is clicked the function is called, but it does not do anything. The Javascript at the bottom will give you an error, but even if it was valid Javascript it would still give you an error because the variable `pass` is not defined in the global scope; it was defined inside the function. Once the function has run, the variable will be forgotten.

It would be better to add a click handler on the button instead:

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- The button -->
<button id="my-button">Chat</button>

<script>
    // Get the button
    var myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");

    // Set a click handler on the button
    myButton.onclick = function () {

        // Get the page
        var page = prompt("What's the password?");

        // Set a new location for the window; this sends the
        // current page to the new page
        window.location = page + ".html";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pass` variable is only defined inside the `testFunction`, so you cannot access it when you try to call `open.window`.

Try returning `pass` in `testFunction` and passing that result to `open.window`

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this sort of stuff. Could you elaborate on how to do this? I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: Your open.window function gets executed when the page loads, but you only prompt the user when they click on the button. Move the open.window into your testFunction and remove the script tag that is after the button.

Comment: (If that's how you reply), this is my new code, but it still doesn't work: http://pastebin.com/ZFUfre0W

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for:

```
function testFunction() {
    // Prompt user for input
    var str1 = window.prompt("What's the password?");
    // Append .html to user input
    var str2 = ".html";
    // Open new window with concatenated result
    window.open( str1.concat(str2) );
}
```

You can then remove the:

```
<script>
    open.window(pass)
</script>
```

Here it is working: https://jsbin.com/gewudaruda/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the first script tag with the one below.
It is recomended to define the type of script with the 'type' attribute of the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction() {
    var str1 = prompt("What's the password?");
    window.open(str1+".html");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In HTML5, the type attribute is optional and will default to `text/javascript` as per http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type